# Which availability zone does the Amazon EC2 Spot Instance price on official site belong to?

Tags: amazon-ec2

We can see spot price for different availability zones in a specific region in the EC2 web console. However there is only one price shown on the official web site for a specific instance type in a specific region. What is the relationship between spot price that is displayed on official site and the these shown in the web console (for different zones)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to this page: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot-instances/

Amazon states: 'The following table displays the Spot Price per Region and instance type (updated every 5 minutes). In addition to Linux/Unix and Windows, we also offer Spot Instances for Amazon EC2 running SUSE Linux Enterprise Server. Spot Instances are not currently supported in the AWS GovCloud Region.'

You can select the region using the drop down selector. The prices are updated every 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I am actually wondering which availability zone does the price shown on the page you cited belongs to. Or it's derived according to some rules set by Amazon, for example the lowest among all availability zones. Any ideas?

Comment: The site that I referenced shows the price for the region currently selected in the drop down field. I am looking right now at m1.small Linux instances in the US-East region and all availability zones a-d are listed as .270. This is consistent with the pricing page for the aggregate Region. 

If you look at the Cluster GPU Instances - Quadruple Extra Large: Zone us-east-1a is currently $2 and us-east-1b is $0.665 which the page I cited has listed as $0.665 per hour.

Therefore I would conclude that the page in question lists the lowest price for that instance type for the Region.